# How to Explode data from database in controller of CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a question, I want to change string data from database using explode, because the data is imploded before when I post it to the database. Here's my controller

```
    public function add_detail()
    {
        $symptoms_id = implode(',', $this->input->post('symptoms_id'));
        $CF_user = implode(',', $this->input->post('CF_user'));
        $data = array(
            'symptoms_id' => $symptoms_id,
            'CF_user' => $CF_user

        );
        $this->db->insert('consultation_detail', $data);
        redirect('User/consultation_result', $data);
    }
```

That function is to implode and it works, but I want to make a function in controller too for explode the data.

I just try like this

```
    public function consultation_result()
    {
        $data['consultation_detail'] = $this->db->get('consultation_detail')->row();
        $CF_user = explode(',', $CF_user);
    }
```

But it said undefined $CF_user , I'm sorry because I'm newbie :(

Comment: Well wherever you see an `implode()` replace it with an `explode()` is that not obvious? Or am I missing something

Comment: I have edited my question

Comment: Maybe `$data['consultation_detail']['CF_user']` or just `print_r($data)` to find out where things are and what the are called

Comment: It says undefined because `$CF_user` is undefined here, you are assigning the value `$data['consultation_detail']`, but exploding the other one.  Try either `$CF_user = $this->db->get('consultation_detail')->row();` or `$CF_user = explode(',', $data['consultation_detail']);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
public function consultation_result($data)
{
    return explode(',', $data);
}
```

and use like this

```
$data = array(
        'symptoms_id' => consultation_result($this->input->post('symptoms_id')),
        'CF_user' => consultation_result($this->input->post('CF_user'))
    );
```